# In Incredibles 2, why didn't anybody realize this?

Tags: pixar, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

In *Incredibles 2*, the Supers are:

> forced to wear hypnotizing glasses.

The Incredible kids pick up on this right away but no one in the general public seems to.

Since this is so incredibly obvious, there's probably a reason why not. What is it?

Comment: You realise what may be "obvious" from an out-of-universe perspective may not necessarily be the case from an in-universe perspective, right? This is a children's film. It was likely very intentional that the googles be "obvious" otherwise the children would just be left muddled, however from an in-universe perspective it's supposed to be as subtle as the aliens tapping your brain waves. This does _not_ make it a plot hole, as the logic of the plot flows _perfectly_ with this addition.

Comment: @Edlothiad So thats an answer. It doesn't negate the question. (Though it doesn't reallly explain why the Incredible kids figured it out immediately.)

Comment: Because they are Incredible?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot (spoiler alert) The son isn't that bright. At least not as bright as an adult (see math subplot of the movie,) Yet he's the one who figures it out.

Comment: So being a maths genius means you have excellent common sense? The two are not related, being clever in one area doesn't make you clever everywhere. Visa versa being not so clever somewhere doesn't mean you are not so clever everywhere.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Everyone in the world has no common sense, just the Incredible kids? Someone should have realized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Winston does pick up on this when the Supers walk out for the signing on the ship.

He asks Evelyn something along the lines of, *"What's with the new masks?"*

To which Evelyn replies, *"Yeah, they've got night vision."*
<sub>The quotes are not exact just from my memory, but the point is what counts.</sub>

Being that Evelyn is the tech guru, it wouldn't seem out of the ordinary for them to receive new tech upgrades.  Also, remember the kids already know something is amiss because Bob has to go rescue Helen.

Answer (score 8):

The Incredibles kids also realize this because they witness Frozone, who was trying to help them escape the hench-heroes in "The Incredibile", suddenly change sides and start attacking them as soon as the goggles are slipped on him. That's a pretty clear cause-and-effect, even for Dash.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I've changed the "in-kid-ibles" to the Incredibles kids. But if you do want something catchier, might I suggest the "Incredi-kids"